# Split a string on a certain character only if it doesn't follow directly after another particular character

Tags: python, string

I have the following code line which is splitting the string `data2` up into a list upon instances of a white space:

```
string_list = data2.split()
```

However in some of my data there are dates in the format `"28, Dec"`. Here the above code is splitting on the white space between the date and the month when I don't want it to. Is there a way I can say "split on the white space, but not if it is after a comma"?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839645/ruby-string-split-with-regex

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

```
>>> re.split('(?<!,) ', 'blah blah, blah')
['blah', 'blah, blah']
```

From the link:

> `(?<!...)` Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded
>   by a match for .... This is called a negative lookbehind assertion.
>   Similar to positive lookbehind assertions, the contained pattern must
>   only match strings of some fixed length. Patterns which start with
>   negative lookbehind assertions may match at the beginning of the
>   string being searched.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.split` with a negative lookbehind expression:

```
re.split(r'(?<!,)\s','I went on 28, Dec')
Out[53]: ['I', 'went', 'on', '28, Dec']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split using a regular expression and utilize look-behind expressions to make sure that you don’t split on a whitespace character that is preceded by a comma:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'foo bar 28, Dec bar baz'
>>> re.split('(?<!,)\s', s)
['foo', 'bar', '28, Dec', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to refloat this thread, but I was trying to decode sqlite cells, and something seems odd to me. I´ll explain. I´m trying to code two different numbers into one cell by creating a string with a 0 in between and then numerizing it, so for example:
`a=4`
`b=7`
`c=str(4)+'0'+str(7)`

The problem is when the first number is 10, so I´m using this
`re.split('0([1-9])','1003')`
`['10','3','']`

Why I´m getting a trhee lenght list when it should be just 2?