# Delete substring when it occurs once, but not when twice in a row in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I know how to delete or replace a substring. But I want it only under the condition that the substring occurs non-repetive. I have made a workaround which looks very ugly and I want to know if there is a better solution.

Assuming the following string:

```
test = "Hello\n,I am here now.\n\nSo what's the problem?"
```

The first `"\n"` should be deletet, however the second `"\n\n"` should not.

To do so I I replace the `"\n\n"` with something that would never be in a normal conversational string, like:

```
x = test.replace('\n\n','42#*#')
x = x.replace('\n','')
x = x.replace('42#*#','\n\n')
```

Which works, but I want to know if there would be a nicer solution to this problem?

**edit**: I tried the solution from [Split a string on a certain character only if it doesn't follow directly after another particular character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547113/split-a-string-on-a-certain-character-only-if-it-doesnt-follow-directly-after-a)

However, when using the following regular expression:

```
re.split('(?<!,)\n', test)
```

I will get the following result:

```
['Hello', ',I am here now.', '', "So what's the problem?"]
```

So both `\n` and `\n\n` were deleted, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine lookahead and lookback assertion:

```
re.sub(r'\n(?!\n)(?<!\n\n)', '', test)
```

Comment: thank you. This actually worked, instead of the marked duplicate

Comment: @Kev1n91 I also voted to reopen the question. It's not a duplicate of the linked one.

Comment: I like this order of lookarounds.