# How can I replace the first occurrence of a character in every word?

Tags: python, regex

How can I replace the first occurrence of a character in every word?

Say I have this string:

```
hello @jon i am @@here or @@@there and want some@thing in '@here"
#     ^         ^^        ^^^                   ^          ^
```

And I want to remove the first `@` on every word, so that I end up having a final string like this:

```
hello jon i am @here or @@there and want something in 'here
#     ^        ^        ^^                   ^         ^
```

Just for clarification, "@" characters always appear together in every word, but can be in the beginning of the word or between other characters.

I managed to remove the "@" character if it occurs just once by using a variation of the regex I found in [Delete substring when it occurs once, but not when twice in a row in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49077427/1983854), which uses a negative lookahead and negative lookbehind:

```
@(?!@)(?<!@@)
```

See the output:

```
>>> s = "hello @jon i am @@here or @@@there and want some@thing in '@here"
>>> re.sub(r'@(?!@)(?<!@@)', '', s)
"hello jon i am @@here or @@@there and want something in 'here"
```

So the next step is to replace the "@" when it occurs more than once. This is easy by doing `s.replace('@@', '@')` to remove the "@" from wherever it occurs again.

However, I wonder: is there a way to do this replacement in one shot?

Comment: Do you need a strictly regex answer?

Comment: @SayandipDutta in principle, yes, but I would be also curious to see other ways to do the same without a regex :)

Comment: Just to make sure, could there be string like: `@Hello@There` where `@` would not be consecutive?

Comment: @JvdV no, there won't be such a case.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would do a regex replacement on the following pattern:

```
@(@*)
```

And then just replace with the first capture group, which is all continous @ symbols, minus one.

This should capture every `@` occurring at the start of each word, be that word at the beginning, middle, or end of the string.

```
inp = "hello @jon i am @@here or @@@there and want some@thing in '@here"
out = re.sub(r"@(@*)", '\\1', inp)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
hello jon i am @here or @@there and want something in 'here
```

Answer (score 37):

How about using `replace('@', '', 1)` in a generator expression?

```
string = 'hello @jon i am @@here or @@@there and want some@thing in "@here"'
result = ' '.join(s.replace('@', '', 1) for s in string.split(' '))

# output: hello jon i am @here or @@there and want something in "here"
```

The int value of `1` is the optional `count` argument.

[`str.replace(old, new[, count])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

> Return a copy of the string with all
>   occurrences of substring *old* replaced by *new*. If the optional argument
>   *count* is given, only the first *count* occurrences are replaced.

Comment: That's a clever trick! Since replace's third parameter is `replace(search, replace, max_matches)`, it just replaces the first one on every word.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' yes, it's called `count`, I added the description from the docs.

Comment: Watch out for this side effect: in case you have several white spaces ('      '), they will be lost and replaced by a single ' '.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `re.sub` like this:

```
import re

s = "hello @jon i am @@here or @@@there and want some@thing in '@here"
s = re.sub('@(\w)', r'\1', s)
print(s)
```

That will result in:

```
"hello jon i am @here or @@there and want something in 'here"
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = "hello @jon i am @@here or @@@there and want some@thing in '@here"
>>> re.sub('@(\w)', r'\1', s)
"hello jon i am @here or @@there and want something in 'here"
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/OgrfAF/1)

```
(?<!@)@
```

You can try this.
See demo.

Answer (score 2):

Was pondering for cases what if only the last char is `@` and you don't want to remove it, or you have specific allowed starting chars, came up with this:

```
>>> ' '.join([s_.replace('@', '', 1) if s_[0] in ["'", "@"] else s_ for s_ in s.split()])
"hello jon i am @here or @@there and want some@thing in 'here"
```

Or, suppose you want to replace `@` only if it is in first n characters

```
>>> ' '.join([s_.replace('@', '', 1) if s_.find('@') in range(2) else s_ for s_ in s.split()])
"hello jon i am @here or @@there and want some@thing in 'here"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python3 program to remove the @ from String


def ExceptAtTheRate(string):
    # Split the String based on the space
    arrOfStr = string.split()

    # String to store the resultant String
    res = ""

    # Traverse the words and
    # remove the first @ From every word.
    for a in arrOfStr:
        if(a[0]=='@'):
            res += a[1:len(a)] + " "
        else:
            res += a[0:len(a)] + " "

    return res


# Driver code
string = "hello @jon i am @@here or @@@there and want some@thing in '@here"

print(ExceptAtTheRate(string))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Note that the _@_ within _some@thing_ and _'@here_ should also be removed, as per my requirements.