# Splitting the string with last underscore

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string like `"a_b_c"` or `"a_b_c_d"` or `"a_b_c_d_e"`. I want to split the string at the last underscore.

```
**input**
'a_b_c'
**output**
a_b
c

**input**
'a_b_c_d'
**output**
a_b_c
d
```

I have done the following:

```
a='a_b_c'
a=a.split('_')
last=a.pop
a.delete(last)
p a.join("_")
p last
```

and achieved the result, but I don't think this should be done this way. I hope there is some regular expression to achieve this. Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`String#rpartition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-rpartition) that searches for a given pattern form the right end of the string and splits when it finds it.

```
'a_b_c_d_e'.rpartition(/_/)
=> ["a_b_c_d", "_", "e"]

s = 'a_b_c_d_e'
parts = s.rpartition(/_/)
[parts.first, parts.last]
=> ["a_b_c_d", "e"]
```

EDIT: applying advices from the comments:

```
'a_b_c_d_e'.rpartition('_').values_at(0,2)
=> ["a_b_c_d", "e"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to split? How about just replacing the `_` with a space? e.g. using [`rindex`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-rindex) and [`[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)

```
a[a.rindex('_')] = ' '
```

I didn't do a benchmark, but `split` creates a new array, which typically requires more resources, at least in other languages.

EDIT: as the question was edited, its now clear the OP is asking for a list instead of a string output

Answer (score 2):

Split it with regex:

```
a.split(/_(?=[^_]+$)/)
```

Explanation:

> matches the character _ with positive Lookahead (?=[^_]+$)
>
> Match a single character not present in the list below [^_]+ and 
>   $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Comment: @rene Quite same reason, but I know it due to some famous question, or can get with little research https://stackoverflow.com/q/12839645/10522579

Answer (score 2):

You can also get values as below,

```
> a = a.split('_')
> a[0..-2].join('_')
# => "a_b_c_d" 
> a[-1]
# => "e"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'a_b_c_d_e'.split /_(?!.*_)/
  #=> ["a_b_c_d", "e"]
```

The negative lookahead `(?!.*_)` requires that following the match of the underscore there is no other underscore in the string.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you know this string follows this format:

```
str = 'a_b_c_d_e'
# Remainder
str[0...-2]    # -> 'a_b_c_d'

# Last symbol
str[-1]        # -> 'e'
```

Comment: it works only if the part after the last `_` has lenght of one.